# Как реализовать отправку таблицы на php? Работа с тегами

Tags: php, form, table

Возможно ли в PHP работать с тегом `<tabel>` также как и с тегом `<form>`? То есть делать формы регистрации, менять значения в БД и т.д.. Мне очень надо это реализовать.

Comment: Всё можно. Дерзайте

Answer (score 1):

Надо будет создавать форму `<form>` в виде таблицы `<table>`. А дальше уже работать на стороне веб сервера. Если захотите редактировать по одному значению, типа кликнули на поле в таблице, оно превратилось в текстовый `<input>` со значением, вы ввели значение, нажали `ENTER` и данные ушли на сервер, то тут надо будет еще `ajax` прикручивать. Такая штука называется "inline редактирование".